# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined at HttpXhrBackend

Tags: angular

I am following a tutorial about using Angular HttpInterceptor but I am getting an error when I call the handle() method

//next.handle();

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined at HttpXhrBackend.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXhrBackend.handle (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:31148:17) at eval (eval at push../src/app/services/authInterceptor.service.ts.AuthInterceptorService.intercept (http://localhost:4200/main.js:756:9), <anonymous>:1:6) at AuthInterceptorService.push../src/app/services/authInterceptor.service.ts.AuthInterceptorService.intercept (http://localhost:4200/main.js:756:9) at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:30859:33) at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:31450:25) at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:30859:33) at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:31494:27) at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:30699:184) at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:143493:27) at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:143483:18)


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{
  intercept(req,next){
    console.log(req);
    return next.handle();
  }

}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?, because the request is being logged okay.

I am using Angular version 7.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please send `req` in handle

```
intercept(req,next){
   console.log(req);
   return next.handle(req); <--- here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sheik for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(req);
    return next.handle(req);
  }
```